# How to use contains() with a set of strings in XSLT

Tags: xslt

I have the following XML snippet:

```
<figure customer="ABC DEF">
    <image customer="ABC"/>
    <image customer="XYZ"/>
</figure>
```

I'd like to check if the figure element's customer attribute contains the customer attributes of the image elements.

```
<xsl:if test="contains(@customer, image/@customer)">
    ...
</xsl:if>
```

I get an error saying:

> a sequence of more than one item is not allowed as the second argument of contains

It's important to note that I cannot tell the values of the customer attributes in advance, thus using xsl:choose is not an option here.

Is it possible to solve this without using xsl:for-each?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In XSLT 2.0 you can use:

```
test="image/@customer/contains(../../@customer, .) = true()"
```

and you will get a `true()` result if any of them are true.  Actually, that leads me to suggest:

```
test="some $cust in image/@customer satisfies contains(@customer, $cust)"
```

but that won't address the situation where the customer string is a subset of another customer string.

Therefore, perhaps this is best:

```
test="tokenize(@customer,'\s+') = image/@customer"
```

... as that will do a string-by-string comparison and give you `true()` if any of the tokenized values of the figure attribute is equal to one of the image attributes.